# Simulate a mobile browser

Tags: python, android, web-crawler, appium

Faced a creative challenge. I ask for help with advice

The browser must be mobile, in an emulated android or pretend to be mobile

Found http://appium.io/ and http://selendroid.io/ platforms

Unfortunately, I could't been adapted work with a Linux server.

Maybe there is something simpler? Can I take some banal flap or regular selenium and use? This is just a data mining tool. Please hint what can I use? Also does not solve the problem. He sees that this device is for the client and most importantly. If I will solved the problem with swipe,  then how to pretend to be, for example, android.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly- is this because of a swipe that is why you need to use the mobile

Or 
Because the site is different from regular desktop site?

If it is a regular but you can do it in mobile size, you may do it using selenium. If the swipe is within the web and not native this can be done with selenium too.

If it involves some form of native , then using appium would be preferable.

Comment: thank you, i told about how pretend mobile device  because google sees the real device

Comment: if it is just faking in a mobile browser , a chrome in device layout should work most of the time. You can test out more different browsers easily with selenium.

However, if it is a see and look feeling with the mobile emulator / simulator , you will need appium. The bulk of the scripts should be similar with appium and selenium in this case. The main difference is how to setting up the drivers for both cases.